# Data Augmentation for Inception v3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use inception v3 to classify images but my dataset is very small (can't have more img than that) and I'd like to augment it with transformations such as rotation or inversions. I'm new to TF and can't figure out how to do so, I've read the documentation for the `ImageDataGenerator` which should augment my data but when training I still get the error that states that I don't have enough data. I could use masks also but don't know how to implement in tf.
Can someone enlighten me ? Thanks a lot for any input

Here's my code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 180,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True)
 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 180,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True)

 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size = 100,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary',
                                                    target_size = (224, 224))


validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                          batch_size  = 100,
                                                          class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                          target_size = (224, 224))
base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (224, 224, 3),
                                include_top = False,
                                weights = 'imagenet')
for layer in base_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

%%time
x = layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                 
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)          
 
model = Model( base_model.input, x)
 
model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001),loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['acc'])
callbacks = myCallback()
 
history = model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            validation_data = validation_generator,
            steps_per_epoch = 100,
            epochs = 10,
            validation_steps = 10,
            verbose = 2,
            callbacks=[callbacks])
```

Error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 1000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `batch_size` attribute from both `flow_from_directory`? Because basically `batch_size` in the training set may affect the `steps_per_epoch` and `batch_set` in the validation set may affect the `validation_step`. When the count doesn't match/provided data is insufficient for each epoch by the `batch_size`, such error will be raised.

Comment: Just tried and got the same error

Comment: Or have you tried removing the steps per epoch and validation steps??

Comment: I've managed to run it with ```steps_per_epoch = 3, epochs = 10, validation_steps = 3,``` but have very sad results aha

Comment: Well, you can try adding more layers, increasing the epochs (without increasing steps/epoch, batch size, and validation_steps), picking another optimizer and change the learning rate of the optimizer as well.

Comment: Yes I will try running 100 epochs and moving the parameters, and I think I'll try adding transformated images to inflate the dataset. Thanks !

Comment: What actual error message you are getting? Please include it verbatim in your question.

Comment: Added the message !

Answer (score 0):

As you are using generators, you will have to calculate the number of steps per epoch as follows:

```
steps_per_epoch=(data_samples/batch_size)
```

OR

You could let the model figure out how many steps are there to cover an epoch. Did you try running it without the `steps_per_epoch` parameter?

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!